# Late Binding to an Active COM object

Tags: c#, ui-automation

In short: My application needs do late binding to non-singleton UI COM control.
How does it implemented?

The long story:
As part of UI automation project on ActiveX.exe application I need to create client side provider (proxy) for the UI controls under test.
I found these links explaining how to do it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307850.aspx
and 
[Introducing_IAccessibleEX.doc](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=introducing_IAccessibleEx.doc&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http://www.atia.org/files/public/Introducing_IAccessibleEx.doc&ei=sO5hT7uCJqXT4QSA7LTnBw&usg=AFQjCNFNXkZdI69t9MF5KdAIBBeTUlaxuA)

The problem is how to do so in C# code

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# - " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: sorry - my bad

Comment: @HansPassant - as far as I got it White enables only the IAccessible part of non-.Net objects to be accessed. This limits to a list of specified properties. I need to refer to the Main object interface via IAccessibleEx. Am I wrong here?